# cannot push to github - no error?

Tags: git, github, push

when i type git push origin master into the terminal nothing happens. The terminal doesn't output anything. I have to CTRL C to get it to respond to inputs again. I wish I could be more descriptive but I don't even get an error message.

Comment: Try `git remote show`.

Comment: Also, how long do you wait? this could simply be a connection *attempt*, being interrupted.

Comment: Use the `--verbose` option to get more details of what's going on.

Comment: so with verbose it printed "ssh: connect to host gitbub.com port 22: Connection timed out""fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Comment: git remote show outputs "origin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ssh doesn't go through for any reason, you can try and switch to an https url, to see if the issue persists:

```
git remote set-url origin https://<your_account>@github.com/<your_account>/<your_repo>
```

That way, you can check if the problem is purely an ssh one, or if it is a more general github network access one.

Comment: so now I'm getting: "error:The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://admiralakbar@github.com/admiralakbar/rshell/info/refs" ... "fatal: HTTP request failed"

Comment: @MohammadAkbar did you enter your GitHub account password (which should have been asked by the `git push`)?

Comment: yeah i did, the error comes after i am prompted for my password.

Comment: @MohammadAkbar do you have 2fa set up for your GitHub account? (as in https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication/ and https://help.github.com/articles/providing-your-2fa-authentication-code/)

Comment: sorry for the late reply been very busy this week. No I do not have 2fa for my account

Comment: @MohammadAkbar is `git remote -v` returning an `origin` set to `https://admiralakbar@github.com/admiralakbar/rshell`?

Comment: yes both origin fetch and origin push are both set to https://admiralakbar@github.com/admiralakbar/rshell